# Run batch file with command prompt open in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduler, prompt

I need to run a bat file with `Window TaskScheduler` and, to check the progress of the operation, I'd like to have the cmd prompt open while the bat runs.

I have recently changed one setting in the task properties:

[image]

With the **old setting** the cmd prompt was launched/showed automatically, instead with the new one I can't see it and find a way to show it.

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking "Do not store password...". I had this issue previously, and checking that box has miracolously solved it for us, hopefully it'll work for you as well.

Comment: @Alex does it work also when the user is not currenty logged in the system?

Comment: we set it up using a service account, which nobody have ever logged on with, and it was working. If you are concerned, you can set up a batch file for example to copy a text file to the desktop, schedule it using this way, log off, and log back once completed. I remember we had a hard time with this as we migrated a lot of scheduled tasks from 2003 to 2008 Server, and this needed some time to figure out.